# Laravel PHPUnit gets "ErrorException: Illegal string offset 'address' " when testnig Maillable hasFrom(...) method

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mailer

Here's my Mailable class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class OrderConfirmation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $subject;
    public $from;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message, $subject, $from)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($this->from)
            ->subject($this->subject)
            ->view('emails.orders.confirmation');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to check that mail has certain From address like this:

```
Mail::fake();
$customer = 'test@test.com';
$from = 'from@test.com';
Mail::to($customer)->queue(new OrderConfirmation('Some Message', 'Some Subject', $from));

Mail::assertQueued(OrderConfirmation::class, function ($mail) {
     return $mail->hasFrom('from@test.com');
});
```

but it gets "ErrorException: Illegal string offset 'address' "

/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php:597

Laravel 5.6

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Can you also add your `OrderConfirmation` class?

Comment: Added to the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting this issue is because you're overriding the `$from` property in the `Mailable` class.

You could remove the `$from` property you have set up in the class and call the `from()` method from the constructor:

```
public $message;

public function __construct($message, $subject, $from)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->from($from);
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.confirmation');
}
```

Alternatively, you could rename the `$from` property to something like `$fromAddress`.

**NB** The same was happening with `subject` as well but since the `subject()` method is simply there to assign a value to the subject property on the class is wasn't actually causing an issue.

Comment: Oh, my gosh! I just totally forgot that this class extends the Mailable! Thanks that you have pointed that out!